# Pythonic way to merge two lists

Tags: python

I want to append value to an existing dictionary. Here is my code:

```
tmp_result = [{'M': 8}, {'N': 16},]
cross_configs = [({'device': 'cpu'},), ({'device': 'cuda'},)]

import copy
generated_configs = []
for config in cross_configs:
    for value in config:
            new_value = copy.deepcopy(tmp_result)
            new_value.append(value)
            generated_configs.append(new_value)

print (generated_configs)

Output: 
[[{'M': 8}, {'N': 16}, {'device': 'cpu'}], [{'M': 8}, {'N': 16}, {'device': 'cuda'}]]
```

I don't like the inner loop which does deepcopy and append. What is a pythonic way to do that?

Comment: Why the lists of single pair dictionaries?

Comment: This does not "append" values to dictionaries; this appends additional single-entry dictionaries to a list.  Your result is two lists of three independent dictionaries each.  What problem are you trying to solve with this data structure?

Comment: probably you meant to name the title as "Merge 2 lists"

Comment: I don't see how you're appending to a dictionary.  You seem to be dealing with lists of lists who elements just happen to be single-key dictionaries, or sets/tuples of one dictionary each.  Are you ultimately trying to take [a,b,c] and [(c),(d)] and return [ [a,b,c], [a,b,d] ]?

Comment: This is part of a big project, I don't have control of the inputs which are from other part of that program.

Comment: That does not really explain why someone thought it might be a good idea to pack a single entry dict into a list into a list. Maybe suggesting a refactoring of the interface is worthwhile as it can help avoid poor performance and hard to maintain source. Furthermore it is not really clear why you would need a deep copy. Are the lists altered afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a list-comprehension:

```
[tmp_result + list(x) for x in cross_configs]
```

**Example**:

```
tmp_result = [{'M': 8}, {'N': 16},]
cross_configs = [({'device': 'cpu'},), ({'device': 'cuda'},)]

print([tmp_result + list(x) for x in cross_configs])
# [[{'M': 8}, {'N': 16}, {'device': 'cpu'}], [{'M': 8}, {'N': 16}, {'device': 'cuda'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested list comprehension will suffice; the explicit call to `dict` is sufficient to avoid the need for `deepcopy` given the example shown.

```
generated_configs = [[dict(y) for y in tmp_result + list(x)] for x in cross_configs]
```

If you object to `tmp_result + list(x)`, use `itertools.chain` instead.

```
from itertools import chain
generated_configs = [[dict(y) for y in chain(tmp_result, x)] for x in cross_configs]
```

Comment: Couldn't nested list-comprehension be avoided as in my answer?

Comment: `list(x)` will only make a shallow copy of the tuple, meaning each sublist will share a reference to the same device dict. The call to `dict` ensures that each `dict` in the result is distinct. (It's not equivalent to a *deep* copy of each list, in the event that the `dict`s themselves contain references to mutable objects, but it is sufficient for the `dict`s shown in the question.)

Comment: It's almost certainly not an issue for the example show, since the two `dict` literals will create separate objects. But consider something like `d1 = {'device': 'cpu'}; d2 = {'device': 'cuda'}; cross_configs = [(d1,), (d1,), (d2,), (d1,), (d2,)]`.